Use of Dom in echarts in charts.int(Dom) vs echarts.init(document.getElementById(id));
I see some use:
var dom = document.getElementById('id');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);

which allows reuse of the dom.  I can see where it would be useful with variables in the dom, but how do you change the variable values each time so you could create a specific chart style, reuse the dom but with new vales for the data, labels, etc?
Is there a way to set the variable referenced in the dom to a different variable or values?
For example:
First graph
var x = list1
data: mydictionary[x]

Second graph
var x = list2
data: mydictionary[x]

where mydictonary is a dictionary of lists named list1,list2 ...listn
or even use  a list of the dictionary names such as:
names =[list1,list2 ...listn]
First graph
var x = names[0]
data: mydictionary[x]

Second graph
var x = names[1]
data: mydictionary[x]

vs.
myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('id'));

and incorporating more code.

I would suggest using a const to store the DOM Element for later, as you are already getting it and you might need it later, if you don't, you could always revert to the original method of getting the DOM Element within the args of the function.
If you even might need to use the element later
const dom = document.getElementById('id');
let myChart = echarts.init(dom);

If you know you don't need the element again
let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('id'));


I think this is a personal preference. Some folks may find it preferable to explicitly declare a variable to get the document's id. And another to initialize the charts.
One thing I will mention is that using var is falling out of flavor in post ES6, in favor of let or const.

It's not just personal preference, if you plan to use the DOM element later, then the cleaner code would to declare the element in a const the first time you use it.  There's no point in document.getElementByIding again if you've already do it for said element, just make a variable for it instead
